# Making a window (with no system controls) smaller than the system minimum?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, window

I needed to make a window smaller than the OS minimum, I decided to remove the OS controls and that didnt work (Im still not going to use the system window controls), I would like a solution thats compatble with the OS window controls but I only need the one for no OS window controls. Im kind of new to .Net so please explain how to use this.

Comment: I've read that a few times over now... I really am not sure what you're asking. You seem to want to create a very small window - what is the constraint you're hitting? What's the compatability you're referring to?

Comment: You ask some prertty interesting questions. We're going to need you to elaborate. Lets start with in .Net winforms, each form has properties and the default value for MinimumSize is 0,0. But when you resize the form to itws smallest (on Win7) its actually 130x 40. Now when I set the FormsBorderStyle to hidden and in the InitializeComponent I change clientsize = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 0); - but get this - its still 130x40 - I  cant reduce it any smaller. Is this what your question is asking?

Comment: What's the use case for this? Perhaps there's a better way to solve the problem you're having?

Comment: Nope, I still can't get "smaller than the OS minimum" to make sense. If there *is* a minimum size, then *by definition*, you can't create something smaller than that.

Comment: If there really is a system minimum...why not make the form transparent (and click-throughable), then just make a little rect as big (or small) as you want?

Comment: -1 since 6 people have replied but no elaboration.

Comment: yes what i am asking is how would you make it smaller than the OS minimum of 130 x 40, and I know this isnt the ACTUAL minimum because i've seen toolbar windows smaller than that, and thats what I need. Jeremy Thompson's idea worked for the Width but the Height still needs to get smaller... sorry I couldnt reply sooner I had school

Comment: how do you make it transparent/click-throughable??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the user32 function SetWindowPos to chane the size of the window at the ctor or on load and also set the form's property FormBorderStyle to None.

I've sized the form to 10, 10 and it works like a charm.
The only problem with that is that you would have to implement Minimize, Maximize and Exit buttons (which makes sense, since the standart system buttons wouldn't fit in a tiny window.

Comment: Why does he have to implement them? Would be nice if you could exit the app...but I don't think these features are required.

Comment: Of course, he doesn't have to unless he wants the functionality.

Comment: how do you access the function? im kinda new to C#